# Buck Boost Circuit for Automobile starter circuit

Tags: battery-charging, automotive

One of the major problem with two wheeler like Royal Enfield is that the starter motor wont work efficiently as the battery ages with performance. Morning cold cranking the engine ignition will not start the engine but also weakens the battery life. Can a buck-boost convertor be used to supply steady voltage to starter motor, will this reduce the sudden Amps spike on the battery  and will this really improves that battery life?

Comment: Boost converters will actually worsen the Amps spike in an attempt to deliver constant voltage.

Comment: Could it be that you need to boost the voltage to the ignition circuit rather than the starter motor? If the engine is cranking, but not firing, then you may not be getting sparks.

Comment: Use the kick start - it's a retro design with a few modern parts added. If you want starter motor reliability buy a honda LOL

Comment: But if it's honda, don't buy hybrid, the battery really sucks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that won't help, you still need a certain amount of POWER to start the engine. If the battery is weak it cannot deliver that power. A buck converter can make more current but at lower voltage but that will not start your engine.

The only option I see is to use super capacitors as you can charge these slowly even from a weak battery and then extract the energy in a short time to crank the engine.

Comment: [This fellow](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8miq6sDy0wA) did exactly this, and it works reliably to start a car. Those caps are good down to -40°C.

Comment: @FakeMoustache wow.. great and to the point solution.. Thank you. could you please point me to some links where I can get to know some sample schematics using super capacitors, please.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, no.

Switching power supplies can't do magic, only convert one combination of volts and amps to a different combination of volts and amps, but the output volts x amps product can never exceed the input volts x amps product.  Note that volts x amps is Watts, which is a measure of power.

Put another way, power out can't exceed power in.  Actually since no converter is 100% efficient, power out will be a bit less than power in.

In theory it is possible to make a converter that puts out a fixed 12 V even though the battery voltage sags under load.  However, in practice that just isn't feasible in this case.  The problem is the huge current (and power) requirement of a starter motor.  It can be a few 100 A, which comes out to well over a kW of power.  Such a converter would be heavy, large, and expensive, and therefore just not practical for your application.

And no, this converter would actually be harder on the battery than the bare starter motor.  This comes back to output power of the converter can't exceed input power.  When the battery voltage is low, the converter pulls *more* current from it to get the input power it needs.

To illustrate this better, let's put some numbers on this as example.  Let's say the starter motor draws 200 A at 12 V.  That's (200 A)(12 V) = 2.4 kW.  Yes, *killo*Watts.  Now say the battery voltage drops to 9 V under 200 A load.  The ideal converter would continue to put out 12 V, so the starter will draw 200 A, and the output power is 2.4 kW.  To get that much power from the battery takes (2.4 kW)/(9 V) = 267 A.  Let's say the converter is 90% efficient, so it will actually draw 296 A with 9 V in.  Now consider the battery will probably drop its voltage even more due to the higher current, so the current drawn by the converter will be even higher.

Fundamentally, if the battery can't put out (2.4 kW)/90% = 2.7 kW, then this system can't work.  A converter can't make more power, only rearrange power to a different volts x amps combination.  If the battery can't put out 2.7 kW, then the converter will keep trying to draw more current, the battery voltage will drop, which will make the converter draw even more current, which will cause the battery voltage to drop even more, etc, until the battery voltage collapses altogether and no power is delivered (since the voltage is 0).

You can't cheat physics.

Comment: Thank you for detailed answer and really appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you have a real bike, like a RE, you always have the Mk1 Starting Foot. But back to the question...

Starting a petrol engine sucks current for the starter motor trying to compress cold air, over coming friction from cold oil and all those other mechanical things. If you use a buck-boost, it would have to be for a very high power, as it will still need to give the current draw to the motor (one liner about motors: "voltage gives speed, current gives torque" and it's the torque you need to start the engine).

So, using a DC-DC, you could get the voltage to be good into the motor, but it would still be high current, as the power is still coming from the battery. The easiest way to over come this current problem is to put a large capacitor (depending on the current draw of the starter motor) on the other side of the DC-DC, which is part of what goes into a start-stop system in cars.

So steadying the voltage is possible, but that will be worse for the battery due to higher current losses in the converter.

Put in a system which uses the battery as a long-term store and a capacitor bank for short term would be a possibility.

But then again, so is getting a new battery for the RE....

Comment: "Is to put a large [...] on the other side of the DC-DC" - I think you a word there.

Comment: Yes thanks! Should be fixed now. Kind of important word I missed off...

Comment: Putting in a bank of caps isn't effective. To quote wiki "(supercaps are) 10 times larger than conventional batteries for a given charge" - so this means batteries are going to be more effective in terms of size and weight.

Comment: @Andyaka That depends on what you're optimising for. The OP wanted to reduce strain on the battery from high peak currents.